# Getting an error while converting the data selected for database to int in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm converting the data retrieved from database to the int value but it is giving me the error:

> Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int.

Here is part of my code:

```
$sql    = 'SELECT M_id FROM student_data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1';
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
   $int= intval ($result);
   $int = $int++;
```

I want to convert this data into int so that after incrementing I can put this back into the database.
But I'm unable to find any solution.I have visited all the relevant questions asked before!Can anyone please guide me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the row:

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$int = intval($row['M_id']);
```

Note that you can update the value directly with a single query:

```
UPDATE student_data AS s1
JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) maxid
      FROM student_data) AS s2
ON s1.id = s2.maxid
SET M_id = M_id + 1
```

Comment: Still it's not fetching the value of M_id.

Comment: I can't see any reason why it wouldn't fetch the value. But I've added a way to do the update without needing to fetch it at all.